# Ошибка 404 после переезда сайта

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, редирект, http-status-code-404, google-search

Я перенес мой wordpress веб сайт на другую платформу (duda) и теперь у меня ошибка 404 на некоторые страницы в поиске гугла (таких страниц нет). Как можно сделать редирект к новому сайту? Доступа к старому сайту нет, точнее доступ к wordpress есть, но на нем уже нет страницы.

Comment: Доступ к nginx есть?

Comment: Где ее можно найти?

Comment: Где у вас сайт хостится?

Comment: Что такое "платформа duda"? Как "перенёс"?

Comment: Это siteeditor  где я "пересоздал" сайт. Код сайта с wordpress я перенес туда

Comment: Старый сайт где расположен?

Answer (score 0):

Для создания редиректа в WordPress есть плагин [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).
Для того чтобы создать постоянное перенаправление с помощью HTTP кода 301 нужно:

1. Установить и активировать плагин, перейти в Инструменты -> Redirection.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В открывшемся окне нужно сделать следующее:
   в Source URL нужно указать старый URL-адрес, при переходе на который мы хотим переходить на другую страницу. В Target URL указываем новый URL-адрес, на который мы будем переходить при клике на ссылку, указанную в Source URL.
   Поставьте галочку в Regular expression;

Укажите Source url: `oldsite.com/(.*)`

Target url: `newsite.com/$1`

После того как вы указали URL-ы нажмите кнопку Add Redirection.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Способ через htaccess и другие плагины](https://wpmag.ru/2015/wordpress-redirects/)

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь добавить плагин wordpress пишет мне: "An error occurred while installing Redirection on Any Assembly - Assembly and Installation Services in MD, Washington DC, Northern VA." Судя по всему сайта нету на wordpress, поэтому он ругается. Простите, если туплю.

Comment: @ErwinIlyasov как вы плагин устанавливаете?

Comment: Через сайт Wordpress: там есть поиск плагинов. Я нахожу плагин Redirect и пытаюсь его установить, но он пишет мне: "An error occurred while installing Redirection on Any Assembly - Assembly and Installation Services in MD, Washington DC, Northern VA."

Comment: @ErwinIlyasov Попробуйте [другими способами](https://urbangiraffe.com/articles/how-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin/) установить. • С помощью ручного скачивания •через загрузку по FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать сервис http://redirect.center/ для HTTP редиректа на новый сайт, если вы используете домен третьего уровня www.

Для этого нужно задать ресурсные записи DNS на DNS сервере старого домена.

> Перенаправление http://www.my-domain.com/ на
>   http://www.my-other-domain.com/

```
Host Record: wwwType: CNAMETo: www.my-other-domain.com.opts-uri.redirect.center
```

> ВНИМАНИЕ `.opts-uri.` Параметр отвечает за передачу пути URL-адреса
>   источника конечному URL.
>
> ПАРАМЕТР. `.opts-https.` Перенаправить параметр на https-домен.
>
> Пример: `www.my-domain.com.opts-https.redirect.center`.